# Create an array from a text Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have an input extrapolated reading with telnetlib that is something like this:

```
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  SlotID  BoardName  Status          SubType0 SubType1    Online/Offline
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0     
  1       H80BADPE   Normal                           
  2     
  3       H802SHGM   Normal                           
  4       H802SHGM   Normal                           
  5     
  6     
  7       H805GPFD   Normal                           
  8       H805GPFD   Normal                           
  9       H801SCUN   Active_normal                    
  10      H802SCUN   Standby_normal                   
  11      H805GPFD   Normal                           
  12      H805GPFD   Normal                           
  13      H807GPBH   Normal                           
  14      H807GPBH   Normal                           
  15      H807GPBH   Normal                           
  16      H807GPBH   Normal                           
  17      H807GPBH   Normal                           
  18      H807GPBH   Normal                           
  19      H801X2CS   Normal                           
---- More ( Press 'Q' to break ) ----                                       20    
  21      H801PRTE   Normal                           
  22    
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

is there an agile way to get an indexed array with the SlotID of the BoardName that contains the keyword "GP"?  Like H805**GP**FD or H807**GP**BH

Example of the output that I would need:

```
[0:[7],1:[8],2:[11]...]
```

Thanks

Comment: The output is unclear. It seems to be a mix of a list and a dictionary. And it's unclear if you really need the values from "SlotId" to be a single value in a list. Wouldn't a result like `[7, 8, 11]` be enough?

Comment: yes, it could be enough. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the lines I want to check have 3 values seperated by spaces. Since I don't know how you get the text I defined it as one string called `text` and split it up at the `'\n'` to get single lines. Depending on your input you might have to modify that.

The basic idea: We split the line and check if we get 3 values. If we get three values we check if the second one contains `'GP'`. If this is true we convert the first value to an integer and add it to the result list.

```
text = """

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
SlotID  BoardName  Status          SubType0 SubType1    Online/Offline
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
0
1       H80BADPE   Normal
2
3       H802SHGM   Normal
4       H802SHGM   Normal
5
6
7       H805GPFD   Normal
8       H805GPFD   Normal
9       H801SCUN   Active_normal
10      H802SCUN   Standby_normal
11      H805GPFD   Normal
12      H805GPFD   Normal
13      H807GPBH   Normal
14      H807GPBH   Normal
15      H807GPBH   Normal
16      H807GPBH   Normal
17      H807GPBH   Normal
18      H807GPBH   Normal
19      H801X2CS   Normal
---- More ( Press 'Q' to break ) ----                                       20
21      H801PRTE   Normal
22
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""

result = []
for line in text.split('\n'):
    parts = line.split()
    if len(parts) == 3 and 'GP' in parts[1]:
        result.append(int(parts[0]))

print(result)
```

This will give you.

```
[7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```